# use RabbitMQ with react native

Tags: react-native, rabbitmq

I'm trying to connect to my rabbit mq server using the api : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rabbitmq

unfortunatly I'm getting the error message :

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'this.rabbitmqconnection.initialize')

import:

```
import {Connection} from 'react-native-rabbitmq';
```

my code with demi params:

```
  const queue_name = 'my_queue';

    const config = {
        host:'url',
    port: 80,
    username:'user',
        password:'pass',
    virtualhost: 'virtual'
    };

  ToastAndroid.show('queue_name:'+queue_name, ToastAndroid.SHORT);

  let connection = new Connection(config);

  ToastAndroid.show('connect after new', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
```

thanks for the helpers!

the class the api that used to connect to rabbitMQ :  'Connection'

```
        this.rabbitmqconnection = RabbitMqConnection;
    this.callbacks = {};

    this.connected = false;

    DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('RabbitMqConnectionEvent', this.handleEvent.bind(this));

    this.rabbitmqconnection.initialize(config);
```

Comment: What does `rabbitmqctl status` gives you? That is to ask, does your rabbimq broker/server is running and is accessible?

Comment: it's a server with url, the only problem is that it get exception before even try to connect, the problem is in the Connection class of the api, it uses things that does not exists... see the code of Connection

Comment: the problem is in the rabbitmqconnection.initialize ... it says that is undefiend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, there is a command that is not mentioned in the 
installation

the full installation is :

```
npm install react-native-rabbitmq --save 
npm install
react-native link
```